# Get full property name for MVC client validation for list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am writing a custom MVC validation attribute that is dependent on another named property within the model. Implementing `IClientValidatable` my code looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules
    (ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {            
        var name = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;
        ModelClientValidationRule rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        { ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(name), ValidationType = "mycustomvalidation" };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentproperty", dependentProperty);

        yield return rule;
    }
```

The trouble is that I am trying to use this in a list of elements. The dependent property is rendered in the view with a name of `MyListOfObjects[0].DependentProperty` and the validation rule is rendered as `data-val-mycustomvalidation-dependentproperty="DependentProperty"`

How do I access the full name of the dependent property from within `GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)`so that it renders as `data-val-mycustomvalidation-dependentproperty="MyListOfObjects[0].DependentProperty"`

The model looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public List<Item> MyListOfObjects  { get; set; }

    public class Item
    {
        [MyCustomValidation("DependentProperty")]
        public int MyValidatedElement  { get; set; }

        public int DependentProperty  { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the model(s) and the property your applying this to

Comment: @StephenMuecke edited showing an example

Comment: You don't (and should not) need the _"full name"_ in the attribute. Assuming your using   `protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)`, then `validationContext` is the `Item` model. I assume what you wanting is to get the corresponding `DependentProperty` in your client side script?

Comment: It is for client side validation. I found this solution from [foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) - see the getName function in the MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.js file

Comment: The link wont open correctly for me. I assume it solves your problem but if not I can post the code for you. (you need to get the prefix of the element - up to the last `.` character -, then append the dependent property name and replace any `.`, `[` and `]` characters with `_` to give you the `id` attribute of the other property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the fully qualified property name in the validation attribute, and you cannot determine it in any case because the validation context is (in your case) typeof `Item` (the attribute has no context of of the parent `MyClass`).

Where you do need the full name is in the client side script (when you add the `adapter` to `$.validator.unobtrusive`. The following script will return the `id`attribute of the dependent property

```js
myValidationNamespace = {
  getDependantProperyID: function (validationElement, dependantProperty) {
    if (document.getElementById(dependantProperty)) {
      return dependantProperty;
    }
    var name = validationElement.name;
    var index = name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
    dependantProperty = (name.substr(0, index) + dependantProperty).replace(/[\.\[\]]/g, "_");
    if (document.getElementById(dependantProperty)) {
        return dependantProperty;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

You can then use it when initializing client side validation

```js
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("mycustomvalidation", ["dependentproperty"], function (options) {
  var element = options.element;
  var dependentproperty = options.params.dependentproperty;
  dependentproperty = myValidationNamespace.getDependantProperyID(element, dependentproperty);
  options.rules['mycustomvalidation'] = {
    dependentproperty: dependentproperty
  };
  options.messages['mycustomvalidation'] = options.message;
});
```

Comment: Client side that's pretty much how the foolproof library does it that I linked to. I guess the answer I was looking for is that you can't because the attribute has no context of the parent.